# Web-based calendar where two people can share & edit without logging in

Tags: web-apps, calendar, hosted

I need a web-based calendar where two people can share and edit without logging in.

Google Calendar can share as read-only, but I am looking for a way where a couple can edit and share a web-based calendar without logging in to the site. A public editable calendar.

Comment: Keep in mind that if two people can edit without logging in then __everybody__ in the world can also edit it - what is so bad about having to log in?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. No one knows about the url. Logging in is a hassle.

Comment: Use Chrome or Opera and let it remember passwords.

Comment: If I use Google calendar then I need two accounts there. One for my private use (not shareable) and one for the calendar. Then I have to switch between Google accounts depending on what I want to do. Read my email or use the calendar.   A hassle.

Comment: You can associate the two accounts, that way you can have both open at once & don't have to log out in order to switch

Answer (score 3):

I guess [TEAMUP CALENDAR](http://www.teamup.com/) will be appropriate. It facilitates you to create, maintain and sharing group calendars, which the creators say differentiates it from Google Calendar.  Using the color-coding options, planners can identify program tracks and their main page also says *“no user account required”*

Comment: Nice, but I hope the OP does not have any security or privacy requirements. This calendar has 'security by obscurity', hoping that no one will ever guess/steal/find the generated URL(s). Sending out those URLs by email is security flaw #1 directly at the start of the process ;-)

Comment: I guess you have Linux as your OS.

Comment: I agree that this answers the OPs question & should be awarded the answer (+1), but, like almost every one else here, I think that what he wants to do is ... inadvisable

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Google calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1#h) you can have multiple calendars, some public, some shared with specific people and some private with events colour coded by which calendar they belong to when they appear on your calendar.

- Does require logging in but you can "save passwords" or "keep me logged in on this computer" depending on which computer you are logged into - I have access to by Google stuff **without re-entering my password** on two laptops, *(one Win7 and one Kubuntu)*, one android phone and a tablet plus can access it with the password from internet cafes, etc.
- Shared with specific other people is less likely to be a problem than public
- You can select who can Add/Edit events to shared calendar.
- Android, *and possibly other*, phones will show your calendar events once they have your google login details.
- The URL is easy to remember.